# How to Input Redirect Two Files to Standard Input?

Tags: io-redirection

Is it possible to redirect two or more files to standard input in one command? For example

```
$ myProgram < file1 < file 2
```

I tried that command however, it seemed like the OS is only taking the first file and ignoring the other...

If not, how can I achieve that?

NOTE: concatenating the two files will not help in my case.

Comment: how about using 2 commands, one for each file?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this from bash, it isn't inputting multiple files to standard input, it is called [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

The output is sent to an file descriptor under `/dev/fd/<n>` for each substitution